# Freeswitch : getting error while loading module mod_h323

Tags: freeswitch, opal

I am configuring h323 with freeswitch but while loading `mod_h323` module in freeswitch getting below error.

```
CRIT] switch_loadable_module.c:1520 Error Loading module /usr/local/freeswitch/mod/mod_h323.so
**/usr/local/freeswitch/lib/libh323_linux_x86_64_.so.1.26.5: undefined symbol: _ZN18H235Authenticators19GetEncryptionPolicyEv*
```

Please anyone knows how to fix this error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is well known problem while compiling some of the module in freeswitch.reason for this can be one of these
1. Ptlib and H323plus need is not configured properly or installed correctly
2. package config is not configured to pc files

so for that 
1. first check your library required for h323 is installed correctly and location for the same 
2. find .pc file 
3. configure pkg config path to that library